# Symfony 3.3.6 Adding Controller/View Getting 404 - Cloud9.io

Tags: php, symfony

I have installed and setup `Symfony 3.3.6` on C9.IO.

When I run the app, it loads up and brings me to the default page fine.
[image]

However I am having a problem adding a a custom controller and view. I've followed all of the instructions, but I get a 404 error when trying to access the page/route. This is the url I'm accessing this page by: `https://symfony4-XXXX.c9users.io/test`

I've added a controller named `TestController.php` in the directory `src/Controller/TestController.php`.

In this controller I have the following code:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="test")
     */
    public function testAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('test/test.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I've added the view 'test.html.twig' to the directory 'app/Resources/views/test/test.html.twig'

The code in this file is:

```twig
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <p>This is my test page.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

My routing.yml file is setup as:

```yaml
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

Why can I not access this page? I keep getting a `404` error.

The logs only show:

> [2017-08-10 13:00:13] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
>   route found for "GET /test"" at
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/var/cache/prod/classes.php line 4173
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException(code:
>   0): No route found for \"GET /test\" at
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/var/cache/prod/classes.php:4173,
>   Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException(code:
>   0):  at
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php:47)"}
>   []

Comment: Have you looked in the log to see for more details?

Comment: Yes, see the update/edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the annotation

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="test")
 */
```

By this

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/", name="test")
 */
```

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: I will try to clear cache `php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup -e prod`

Comment: Do I have to clear cache everytime I add a controller/route?

Comment: It is not necessary, but if you have a problem like this, clear it